# How to show data from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

can you please help to solve this issue ? I cannot make it work, I want to retrieve value $result in echo, but it isnt working at all.. Please help :)

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('your_db_name');

$query = "
SELECT COMPANY 
FROM dap_users
WHERE id = 6 
 ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo $result;

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I want to retrieve name of company, but all what it retrieves is "Resource #ID 6"

Comment: You can't echo the result. It's a resource. See the [second example in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the fetch. After you get your result then you need to fetch the data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['COMPANY'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro it works :)
can you please help me with this 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if ($row['COMPANY'] == ' '){
echo "http://domain.com/not-found";  
} else {
echo "http://domain.com/" . $row['COMPANY'] . "";
} 

Basically I want to check if this mysql cell is empty or not

Comment: if(!empty($row['COMPANY'])) {do some thing}  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: thanks bro :) but I found that if its empty there is actually in mysql this 
<td id="val[&amp;where%5Bid%5D=1][company]" onclick="selectClick(this, event, 0);">&nbsp;</td>

so I should do if ($row['COMPANY'] == '&nbsp;'){